# React - Flow & Conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm using Flow with React-Native. I'm having a flow issue raised by VSCode and i don't know how to change my approach to comply with flow types.

```
/* @flow */

type RandomType = {
  id: number,
  unit: string,
};

const renderData = (data: RandomType) => { return data.id };

const getRandomTypeOrEmpty = (isempty: boolean): RandomType | {} => {
    if (isempty) { return {} }
    return { id: 1, unit: 'litres'}
};

const data = getRandomTypeOrEmpty(true);
if (data && data.id ) { renderData(data) };
```

> 16: if (data && data.id ) { renderData(data) };
>                                          ^ Cannot call `renderData` with `data` bound to `data` because property `id` is missing in object type [1] but exists in `RandomType` [2].

**Here is my issue:**

I have a function that provides me **data** which can be of type ***RandomType*** or ***empty object {}***.
And then, i must call a function that has to take a ***RandomType*** argument.

So i call this function according the **data** value with a condition.
However, Flow is still raising an issue even though this function will never be called with a data which is not **RandomType**

How can i fix this error ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your return type on `getRandomTypeOrEmpty` is potentially returning an inexact object `{}` which could have any keys on it. That means it could have an `id` key on it, so checking `data.id` doesn't allow flow to determine that you're dealing with a `RandomType`.

You can return an exact empty object instead, and then the problem goes away:

```
type RandomType = {
  id: number,
  unit: string,
};

const renderData = (data: RandomType) => { return data.id };

const getRandomTypeOrEmpty = (isempty: boolean): RandomType | {||} /* return an EXACT empty object */ => {
    if (isempty) { return {}.freeze } // <-- freeze the type so it's an exact object
    return { id: 1, unit: 'litres'}
};

const data = getRandomTypeOrEmpty(true);
if (data.id ) { renderData(data) }; // <-- only need to check for presence of id
```

[Flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBKAhgHYAmcAtgCq4EC8YA3qmGAJbkBcYpArlQBGeAE4AaNmH6kOGXgGcMojqQDmkgL4BudAGM4pJWFF4KYgCLEMxMEwAU5a8V4kK1OvgCUdgHwsTPAx+UVIwJxsAOi4wHX1DYzUgt0paegB5UQBRKhxsOzB7DgU8XOxeITg4GDwyL1cyVM8CAB8WFpbNMFBA4NCwMjAsgA0AQQBhGjBSvKwwOCEAKzw9DGRgPxYpdg4oQuKZ7B9mXpCw5k1IqFM8AC8CLuANgB4AWlewa7w7ggwAC1+9DACjgnAwAHIFAMwngAB7EVbzJYrDDbU79E5cXgARnE0lk8jA4JgclMCnBmlQcVQBiMawitiYSQwKQ8GWyZSw9mU-DwXl0u0KDOi5DAx0C5lEVhsjmcPh03Re73mpBgc1I31FGFBegBegA1p84KIwDgyWY9AQ4HsuEA)

Comment: Nice answer ! Also, can i go further using lodash ?
Why is checking id specifically and not unit property ?

Can i use _.isEmpty(data) ?

Comment: I haven't worked with _.isEmpty, it may or may not provide the level of type refinement necessary.

You could check `data` instead, either works. The key is that when looking at a RandomType or an empty object, then the presence of *any* key will be enough signal for flow to know it's RandomType. Does that make sense?

Comment: Alright. However, if i ever want to make something generic, i could use a function isEmpty that i could use whatever the RandomType definition is :
tiny.cc/2kyq6y

Comment: Mm, Flow isn't quite that smart and isn't able to retain type refinement inside the `isEmpty` function once you leave it. Read more here: https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/. PS if you like my answer please upvote it. :-)

Comment: I tried doing something [like this](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5sxCBnAUQFsAHfATwApDtbN8AuMAbwF8AlKDDcARnDgwApgENSAUlwALKbgDW5ZMF6owYAE5T8mfaUa0pcKGTYcwAXkdgA5HFEArVfmdgAZL7AAeQ8vADo1KQZyFlt8AVDpbABzfCUHJwAGVD50XBJyfDA3d24eAB8yvjAy3jAoCW4C-VYksCr7MCZ+bjkGAV09QaG9VEJrFio6RiZigQEdPRmPUPq4Rvxm5P6coA) but Flow probably doesn't understand Object.keys that well.

Comment: Yep. They don't support type refinement from Object.keys: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7729#issuecomment-493202549

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [maybe type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/) to indicate an optional property.

```
type RandomNumber = {
  id?: number,
  unit?: string
};

const a: RandomNumber = {}; // works
```

Now your variable of type `RandomNumber` is still valid if empty.

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AJQIYB2AJrALYByArmQEZYBOoAvKAN6KigCWxA-AC5QhGvQYAaTqCqFuKQaADOKBt0IBzRAF8A3MgDGsQstD4hBEuWp1GLdrsRA

Comment: But then my function *renderData* could fail if i don't check that id exists before calling it ?
Ideally, i'd like to force a parameter to contains these properties in order to avoid to check if they exists.

Comment: It would "fail"? It would just return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/* @flow */

type RandomType = {
  id ?: number,
  unit ?: string
};

const renderData = (data: RandomType) :number => { return data.id };

const getRandomTypeOrEmpty = (isempty: boolean): RandomType => {
    return isempty ? {} : { id: 1, unit: 'litres'}
};

const data = getRandomTypeOrEmpty(true);
if (data && data.id ) { renderData(data) };
```